# Delete rows from Berkeley DB using where condition

Tags: berkeley-db

I want to delete multiple rows from Berkeley DB using where condition. For example the query would be like this:

```
DELETE FROM table_name 
WHERE [condition];
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the BDB SQL Interface, which is compatible with SQLite's API, take a look at [BDB SQL Is Nearly Identical to SQLite](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_05/html/bdb-sql/dbsqlbasics.html#identicalusage)